# java.desktop cannot be resolved to a module

Tags: java, eclipse, java-platform-module-system, java-13

I want to import java.desktop to use a BufferedImage:

[image: Import]

But Eclipse shows me an error and says that it cannot be resolved to a module

[image: module error]

Although I added the JRE to the modulepath:

[image: Modulepath]

I am also using Maven for the project but importing an external library works fine.

Comment: after adding this `requires java.desktop;` in `module-info.java` it works for me, and also you can expand `JRE System library` and check there

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

That's what I did as you can see in picture 2.
What do you mean with "checking"?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the newest version of eclipse and the error disappeared.